# Visual paradigm in IntelliJ IDEA integration Mac OSX

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-paradigm

I would like to use Visual paradigm Community Edition in IntelliJ IDEA IDE. From Visual paradigm Integration Menu I select my "install in existing IntelliJ IDEA" location as below. But It said, invalid Path.

```
/Users/mike/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2
```

What is wrong with this location?

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Paradigm go to **Window → Integration → IDE integration...**

In the Visual Paradigm IDE Integration window select the **IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio Integration** checkbox and press **Next** button.

In the next window specify your directory as:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents
```

After the installation finishes you can find a new menu items in your IntelliJ IDEA under the **Tools**:

[image]

Comment: saved me hours... kudos mate <3